# Dismiss current dialog when other dialog shows by other application

Tags: android, ime

I have a trouble with implement IME on android.

When user presses a key, the dialog will be shown.
Then, user drags down notification bar and choose "Select input method", a new dialog appears. But my dialog covers the "Select input method" (called by android).

I want to dimiss my dialog before "Select input method" is shown. How do I do that ?

```
    // This is my source to show Dialog:
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mIme.getApplicationContext());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    builder.setAdapter(mModeAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int position) {
            di.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setTitle(mIme.getResources().getString(R.string.input_method));
    mOptionsDialog = builder.create();
    mOptionsDialog.show();
```

Comment: share a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: Hi Ritaban, I have updated my source code. This is my source code to create dialog, and the another dialog is shown by other application. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user2439755, I show a dialog then other application show a new dialog (via notification bar). I want to dismiss my dialog before a new dialog shown or the new dialog must be in front of my dialog. The screenshot is only a my dialog.

Comment: @Lam: your notification activity is same for both dialogs?

Comment: Is it not possible to call mOptionsDialog.dismiss() inside the notification activity.something like this.               'NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(/*your id*/); 
        mOptionsDialog.dismiss()'